# LIST Data Structures

Tags: list

If there is a List of 1000 elements. What is the worst case comparison needed to search an element?

- O(1)
- O(n)
- 1000

I came across this question in placement session in the same language as I have written above and I know this looks a very trivial question but I have a doubt:
Is this a question about the number of comparisons(because 1000 is also given 
in options) or time complexity to search an element.

According to me, the answer is O(1) because it takes constant time to search an element in constant size LIST.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: "Does List mean Array or Linked List?" why would it make any difference in number of comparisons? "Is this a question about the number of comparisons" from what you have posted - yes. The question is about number of comparisons (" What is the worst case comparison needed to search an element?"). Since there is no additional structure in worst case you'd need to compare every element in list so the answer is 1000.

Comment: If this is referring to a linear search, it should be O(n). See this [wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search).

Comment: jack Mood, How can it be O(n) when the number of elements in a List is 1000.